# How to create query builder was failed in CakePHP 3.7

Tags: cakephp-3.7

I'm setting up query builder in CakePHP 3.7 to get value in single row, inside UsersTable. I want to get row value "where Name = 'Budi'"

I'm tried to solved it by browsing in https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html but doesn't work

```
<?php
//UsersController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Model\Table\UsersTable;
use Cake\Event\event;
use Cake\I18n\Time;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
  public function index
  {
    $query = $users->find()
        ->select(['ID', 'Nama'])
        ->where(['Nama =' => 'Budi']);


        foreach ($query as $users) {
            debug($users->Nama);
        }

        $this->set(compact('users'));
  }

  //code from cake bake all
}
?>
```

the messages error shown here

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: users [APP/Controller\UsersController.php, line 20]

Notice (1024): Undefined property: ErrorController::$Auth in C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\src\Controller\AppController.php on line 57 [CORE\src\Controller\Controller.php, line 388]

Warning (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in file=C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php line=853 [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 48]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 148]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]

Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\klinikucing\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\Debugger.php:853) [CORE\src\Http\ResponseEmitter.php, line 181]

An Internal Server Error Occurred
```

I expect the output is

```
-------------------------------------------------
| Nama    |   Role   | Dibuat      |  Diubah    |
------------------------------------------------- 
| Budi    |  Visitor | 10/04/2019  | 12/04/2019 |
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the model of the controller as well

Use
`$query = $this->Users->find()
        ->select(['ID', 'Nama'])
        ->where(['Nama =' => 'Budi']);`

Comment: Also just FYI, if you're not already aware, the `=` sign in the key is optional, `['Nama' => 'Budi']` works too.

Answer (score 0):

on first line of index function, i think you must define `$users` variable

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
```